# Problem getting fresh data after a promise resolves

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have those 2 functions:

```js
const isScreenShareActive = useSelector(selectIsScreenShareActive);
const toggleScreenshare = useCallback(async () => {
  dipsatch(addTesktopTrack(isScreenShareActive));
}, [isScreenShareActive]);
```

```js
const addDesktopTrack = async (isScreenShareActive) => {
  const response = await requestScreenShare();

  if (isScreenShareActive) {
    return;
  }

  // More code down...

}
```

I want `isScreenShareActive` to be fresh data when called in `addDesktopTrack()`. I tried passing a callback that returned `isScreenShareActive` to `addDesktopTrack()` but that still returned old data. How can I achieve getting fresh data here?

P.S. `isScreenShareActive` is in a different slice than the `addDesktopTrack()` and I don't really want to access the other slice from this slice straight up.

Answer (score 0):

The `isScreenShareActive` value passed to the `addDesktopTrack` action creator is closed over in callback scope. I won't ever be a different value.

You can access the store's current state though. Import the `store` object and invoke the `getState` method.

```js
import { store } from '../path/to/store';

...

const addDesktopTrack = async (isScreenShareActive) => {
  const response = await requestScreenShare();

  const state = store.getState();
  const currentIsScreenShareActive = selectIsScreenShareActive(state);

  if (currentIsScreenShareActive) {
    return;
  }

  // More code down...
}
```

You've tagged the post with `redux-toolkit` so I'd suggest using the `createAsyncThunk` utility function which exposes the store's `getState` function as part of its `thunkAPI`.

Example:

```js
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

...

const addDesktopTrack = createAsyncThunk(
  "addDesktopTrack",
  async (isScreenShareActive, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await requestScreenShare();

    const state = thunkAPI.getState();
    const currentIsScreenShareActive = selectIsScreenShareActive(state);

    if (currentIsScreenShareActive) {
      return;
    }

    // More code down...
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats the route I would normally go, but I have problems accessing the store in a slice, the app just crashes. I decided to make a useEffect that sets this in sessionStorage and then get it from the sessionStorage from inside addDesktopTrack.